# Firestore query doesn’t work in cloud functions but works in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I decided to test Firestore before implementing it into our project. I did a query in the cloud functions and it does not work, although the swift implementation of the same query works. Please tell me what is wrong with the node.js query.

**Update**: This code should return a `UserMatch` model if `matchedUserID` is equal to the parameter that is passed to the function. In the iOS SDK this works well, in Node.js it does not work (nothing is returned) with the same data.

Swift code

```
class func testFirestore(_ matchedUserID: String) {
        let start = Date().currentTimestamp
        let userID = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()?.id ?? ""
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("userMatches").document(userID).collection("matches").whereField("matchedUserID", isEqualTo: matchedUserID)

        db.getDocuments { (querySnap, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("error", error)
                return
            }
            let end = Date().currentTimestamp
            let result = end - start
            debugPrint("testFirestore result is", result)
            guard let documents = querySnap?.documents else { return }
            debugPrint("documents", documents.count)
            for document in documents {
                debugPrint("document", document.data(), "document.metadata")
            }
        }
    }
```

Node.js code from cloud function.

```
exports.testFirestore = function (currentUserID, matchedUserID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('matchedUserID', matchedUserID);
        const userMatchesRef = firestore.collection('userMatches').doc(currentUserID).collection('matches');
        var query = userMatchesRef.where('matchedUserID', '==', matchedUserID);

        return query.get().then(userMatchSnap => {
            if (userMatchSnap.exists) {
                // should be only on
                var userMatch = null;
                userMatchSnap.forEach(doc => {
                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                    if (userMatch === null) {
                        userMatch = doc.data();
                    }
                });
                return resolve(userMatch)
            } else {
                return resolve(null);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            return reject(error)
        })
    })
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have more information what *it does not work* means. what are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: @Jay This code should return a UserMatch model if matchedUserID is equal to the parameter that is passed to the function. In the iOS SDK this works well, in Node.js it does not work (nothing is returned) with the same data.

Comment: Did you step through the js code line by line to ensure each variable contains the data you are expecting? i.e. if you pass in an invalid parameter, it would cause the function to fail.

Comment: Of course, I looked in logs everything was normal, it just always came in null, although 4 models had to come (I made 4 models for the test). Through iOS SDK came exactly 4 models. At the moment I stopped testing Firestore and returned to RD.